# Rshiny includeHTML() greyed out

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shinyApp that has information regarding various quality indicators.
Each indicator has an associated formatted word document.
I want to show the correct documentation, depending on the indicator chose. I have saved the word files as htm files so I can use includeHTML()

```
library(shiny)
library("xtable")

dir <- "H:\\TEMP\\"

print(xtable(mtcars), type="html", file=paste0(dir, "example1.html"))
print(xtable(iris), type="html",   file=paste0(dir, "example2.html"))
print(xtable(cars), type="html",   file=paste0(dir, "example3.html"))


runApp(
  list(
 ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("docselect", "Select:", c("example1.html", "example2.html", "example3.html"))
      , width = 2),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(title = "Empty"),
        tabPanel(title = "Results", uiOutput("DoC"))
      )
    )
  )
)

, server = function(input, output, session){
  output$DoC <- renderUI({includeHTML(path = paste0(dir, input$docselect))
  })
  
}
 )
)
```

This all works well... until I start calling the documents I actually want to call... The app greyed out, without any error in R...

I suspect there might be some hidden formatting that is not allowed, however, I cannot find any other posts with similar issues...

Its not a word-conversion issue per se, because I can open a new word document, write text, add a table, save as htm, and just open this in the App...

EDIT: I just found out the by opening the html in a browser and pressing ctrl+U, you can see the actual html code. The html files created by word have a LOT of definitions it seems. I went to https://word2cleanhtml.com/ and 'cleaned up' the html code. The new cleaned html also doesnt load. Again, just greyed out... not error message...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to replace `includeHTLM('path')` with `HTML(readLines('path'))`.